# Page not submitting in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, javascript, firefox

I've a user control registered in an aspx page.
User control has a textbox and a submit button.
Ascx code of user control is placed under a asp:panel.
Using firefox, when user hits enter key, the page is not submitting to the server.However, this works fine in IE browsers.
Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting defaultbutton="urbuttonid" to the asp:panel

Comment: Whether ur page is submitting or not when using firefox.... ur question is not clear....

Answer (score 0):

Set property DefaultButton="submitbtn" for asp:panel.

Replace **submitbtn** with your asp:button id.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, what the others say. You've probably got a submit button earlier in the page that Firefox is associating you enter key press with.

Use:

```
  <asp:panel .... DefaultButton="btSubmit">
     <asp:textbox ... />
     <asp:button id="btSubmit" ... />
    </asp:panel>
```